# Vue-apollo query doesn't render variables

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, graphql, nuxt.js, vue-apollo

In Nuxt.js, I'm trying to do a query like this with the nuxt [apollo-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module) based in [vue-apollo](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-apollo)

```
apollo: {
    magazines: {
        query: gql`query($id: String!) {
            magazines( where: { url_contains:$id })
            {
              url
              title
              thumbnail     
            }
      }`,
      prefetch: ({ route }) => ({ id: route.params.id }),
      variables() {
          return {
              id: this.$route.params.id
          }
      }
}
```

The query is sent, but the variable `$id` is sent unrendered (in the petition, I can see `query($id: String!)`—instead of `query('my-page-route': String!)`—  and `where: { url_contains:$id }` as it is—instead of `where: { url_contains:'my-page-route' }`

The query is surprisingly valid, as it responds with all the items in the db —so it doesn't apply the `where: { url_contains:$id }`

I have tried with `query($id: String)` but that doesn't change anything. Any hints about what could be going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `filter` instead of `where`?

Comment: I'm querying to a api build with Strapi, and according to the specs, that's the way to go https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/graphql.html#configurations Anyhow, the problem is not if the query is valid or not, but that the $id variable is sent as '$id' instead taking a value.

Comment: Is your graphql endpoint public? Can you share it?
Ideas on the fly:
- Add whitespace `url_contains: $id`,
- Check for non-breaking whitespace,
- Maybe `url_contains` accept array? Try `query($id: [String])` or `query($id: [String!]!)`
- without using prefetch:

Comment: - without using prefetch:
```
data () {
     return {
          id: this.$route.params.id
     }
},
apollo: {
     magazines: {
          query: gql`query($id: Int) {
               magazines (where: { 
                     url_contains: $id
               }) {
                    url
                    title
                    thumbnail
               }
          }`,
          variables(): {
               return {
                    id: this.id
               }
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: @ManUtopiK I can share it via pm if you wish, but the problem doesn't seem to be in the response, but in the bad-formed request

Comment: @ManUtopiK the array after the $id doesn't work (gives an error)

Comment: :/ . In devtools > network, you see your graphql request. Do you see `variables` in your request payload? It's contains `id`?

Comment: @ManUtopiK Yep, there I can see the variable rendered (I didn't realize that there was a variables part in the request), but the response is still unfiltered

Comment: And the variable in this request payload is correctly rendered or you see something like `variables: {id: "$id"}`?

Comment: @ManUtopiK no, it's correctly rendered there. I guess there must be a bug with the api, I will try to ask there.

Comment: Ok! Now you know it's server side :) Do you check your graphql api docs with graphiql or something else? Try it here: https://graphiql-online.com and verify your query...

Comment: Hi @ManUtopiK, sorry I didn't comment back, finally I filed a bug here and I'm waiting for the reply, thanks for your help! https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/3815